# \ in the end of each line of a txt

Tags: python, text

I want to write the pathnames of images into a .txt in python. A create a new line for each path yet It creates an unwanted \ at the end of each image. I tried to strip it yet nothing happens. How can I strip it?

```
for num, name in enumerate(dirNames):
    os.mkdir(name)
    os.chdir(name)
    with open(f'{os.path.basename(name)}.txt', 'w+', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
        for tile in png_cropedShips[num]:
                
                path = os.path.join('tiles', os.path.basename(name), os.path.basename(tile),'\n')
                print(path)
                f.write(path)
        for line in f:
            line.rstrip('\\')
```

The output:

```
tiles\T34TBL20211001T094041\T34TBL_20211001T094041_c38_r9_ndwi.png\
tiles\T34TBL20211001T094041\T34TBL_20211001T094041_c39_r0_ndwi.png\
tiles\T34TBL20211001T094041\T34TBL_20211001T094041_c39_r12_ndwi.png\
tiles\T34TBL20211001T094041\T34TBL_20211001T094041_c39_r13_ndwi.png\
```

Comment: Could you please post your *actual* code? As the syntax highlighting indicates, the code you’ve posted contains a syntax error and wouldn’t execute.

Comment: In your own words, where you have `os.path.join('tiles', os.path.basename(name), os.path.basename(tile),'\n')`, what is the intended purpose of the `'\n'`? Since this is `os.path.join`, what do you expect it to put in between the `os.path.basename(tile)` and the `'\n'`? What do you expect to be the last character of the string? Can you remove the backslash using `.strip` if it is not the last character?

Comment: `r'\'` is an invalid string literal. Your code as you posted it cannot produce any output, because it crashes.

Comment: Take the `\n` out of `os.path.join` and `write` it to the file separately.

Comment: Also, yes: `r'\'` is not a valid string literal. A raw string cannot end with an odd number of backslashes, because Python determines where the string literal ends in the source code *before* it decides what the contents are.

Comment: I  wanted the above output without the last backslash! Taking out of join and write it separately, fixed the problem!!

Answer (score 1):

```py
path = "a\\string\\"
path = path.removesuffix("\\")

print(path)
```

will print:

```py
a\string
```

This should do it, when using backslashes you should place them two times in a string because it kind of ignores the first one.

Answer (score 0):

The correct output was achieved by writing the newline character separately from the images paths!

```
for num, name in enumerate(dirNames):
    os.mkdir(name)
    os.chdir(name)
    with open(f'{os.path.basename(name)}.txt', 'w+', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
        for tile in png_cropedShips[num]:
                path = os.path.join('tiles', os.path.basename(name), os.path.basename(tile))
                
                f.write(path)
                f.write('\n')
```